# How can I retrieve the methods of a Julia macro?

Tags: methods, macros, julia

In Julia, the `methods` function may be used to retrieve the methods of a function.

```
julia> f(::Int) = 0
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(::String) = ""
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> methods(f)
# 2 methods for generic function "f":
f(::String) in Main at REPL[1]:1
f(::Int64) in Main at REPL[0]:1
```

Macros can also have multiple methods.

```
julia> macro g(::Int)
           0
       end
@g (macro with 1 method)

julia> macro g(::String)
           ""
       end
@g (macro with 2 methods)

julia> @g 123
0

julia> @g "abc"
""
```

However, the `methods` function does not seem to work on macros because Julia first calls the macro, due to the fact that they do not need parentheses.

```
julia> methods(@g)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching @g()
Closest candidates are:
  @g(::String) at REPL[2]:2
  @g(::Int64) at REPL[1]:2
```

I tried using an `Expr`ession to contain the macro, but this did not work.

```
julia> methods(:@g)
# 0 methods for generic function "(::Expr)":
```

How can I retrieve the methods of a macro?

Comment: `methods(eval(Symbol("@g")))` worked for me, but there must be a cleaner method

Comment: Cleaner (with no `eval`): `methods(Main.(Symbol("@g")))`

Comment: @DanGetz Nice. But yeah, there *should* be a cleaner method... (By the way, `Main.(Symbol("@g"))` is deprecated, and `getfield(Main, Symbol("@g")` should be used instead.)

Answer (score 2):

I would put a generic macro (`@methods`) inside a module (`MethodsMacro`) in my `~/.juliarc.jl` along with the line: `using MethodsMacro`. This way you'd have it available at every Julia session, something like:

```
julia> module MethodsMacro

       export @methods

       macro methods(arg::Expr)
           arg.head == :macrocall || error("expected macro name")
           name = arg.args[1]
           :(methods($name))
       end

       macro methods(arg::Symbol)
           :(methods($arg)) |> esc
       end

   end
MethodsMacro
julia> using MethodsMacro

julia> @methods @methods
# 2 methods for macro "@methods":
@methods(arg::Symbol) at REPL[48]:12
@methods(arg::Expr) at REPL[48]:6

julia> f() = :foo; f(x) = :bar
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> @methods f
# 2 methods for generic function "f":
f() at REPL[51]:1
f(x) at REPL[51]:1
```